# Changing mouse wheel zoom settings in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, zoom

I'm having a problem with the mouse wheel zoom setting on my macbook trackpad. The zoom occurs far too quickly for any level of precision. I noted this comment in the dev log:

2004-08-14 [gsherman] 0.4.0devel9 Added mouse wheel zoom. Moving wheel forward zooms in by a factor of 2.

How can I change the settings so that zooming occurs by a factor of 1 or .5?

I'm using QGIS 2.6 Brighton.

Answer (score 22):

Open *Preferences* > *Options* menu and go to "Map Tools" (see the screenshot below). The Zoom factor will be available on the main window.

**For QGIS v3.X provide a zoom factor in percentage :**

[image: Zoom wheel QGIS3]

**For QGIS v2.X, just provide a ratio value :**
[image: Zoom wheel]

**Notice that the minimal value is 1.1** ... 1 would just do nothing and a value < 1 would unzoom.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Currently I am using 2.14.3 Essen and a **zoom factor of 1.1** is my sweet spot for zooming with a apple trackpad.

Comment: 110% for QGIS3, where the values are percentages instead of proportions

Answer (score 3):

For QGIS3

setting > option > map Tools > zoom factor

[image: QGIS3]

Answer (score 0):

If you zoom out too far and lose your layers, you can right-click on a layer in the Layers Panel and select **Zoom to Layer**.

Answer (score 0):

To use fine-resolution zooming with the mouse wheel scroll up/down, press one key:

- Windows, Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+scroll up/down
- macOS: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+scroll up/down